# Deregister wordpress script in child theme by js location

Tags: child-theme

I want to dequeue a javascript file which is present in the parent theme. Which is not minified version. I want to keep the minified version in child theme. For that i want to deque the js in parent theme and enque the theme in child theme. I want the deque the js with the location i dont want to use any plugin i want this one to be done through the function.php in child theme.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the wp_dequeue_script() function
The key is to make sure this runs AFTER the script has been enqueued by using the right hook.
You should enqueue your minified version of the script in the usual/correct place as if it was not related to the other script in any way.

Your function could go in functions.php and look something like this

```
function dequeue_parent_script() {
  wp_dequeue_script( 'name-of-parent-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_parent_script', 100 );
```

Comment: there is no name for the script it is like the following <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>

Comment: How is it enqueued? It should appear somewhere in the parent theme functions and they should name it when they enqueue it. If they are not enqueuing their scripts then you would have to override the entire template file that they hardcode the script into and just have that same template name in your them and make your changes there.